# Association through a self-join table

Tags: ruby, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

Let's say we have a model Match as

```
class CreateSomething < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]

  def change
    create_table :matches do |t|
      # a match with 2 user id
      t.integer :first_id 
      t.integer :second_id
      t.boolean :active, default: true # is active or not
    end
  end

  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end

end
```

I want User model to access Matching of whose first_id or second_id equals to current user.
How could I define such a matching without 'where'?
How could I access all the matchers?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # a example with where
  has_many :matching,
           -> { where "first_id==#{id} OR second_id==#{id}" },
           class_name: 'Match'

  has_many :matchers, # then ... how?

end
```

Comment: How do you intend to use this? e.g. will it be `user = User.first` and then `user.matchers`? if so then the then answer is add this to the `User` class `def matchers; Match.where(first_id: self.id).or(second_id: self.id)` if you want eager loading then you need to change the scope to `has_many :matchers, -> {joins("INNER JOIN matches ON users.id IN (matches.first_id, matches.second_id)")}, class_name: Match`. Otherwise a little `Arel` could make this cleaner. Honestly not sure what this is for but a join table would probably be better something like `user_matches`.

Comment: @engineersmnky By declaring these relationships, I want to gain some extra function from rails for free, like: ' user.matchers.create name: 'Edw' ' to create a user and match it with current user, ' user.destroy ' to destroy the user and relative mathing ...

Comment: Not sure if it is possible. @engineersmnky